# Remove object from arrayList using object field value as parameter

Tags: java

I want to remove an object from an ArrayList when I type in on of the object fields value in the input field.

I have a superclass with general info for the different meters I will add.

```
public class Meter
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
public String regNum;
public String workOrNot;
public String location;


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Clock
 */
public Meter(String regNum, String workOrNot, String location)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    setRegNum(regNum);
    setWorkOrNot(workOrNot);
    setLocation(location);
}

//REGISTRATION NUMBER
public void setRegNum(String regNum){
    this.regNum = regNum;
}

public String getRegNum(){
    return regNum;
}

//WORK OR NOT
public void setWorkOrNot(String workOrNot){
    this.workOrNot = workOrNot;
}

public String getWorkOrNot(){
    return workOrNot;
}

//LOCATION
public void setLocation(String location){
    this.location = location;
}

public String getLocation(){
    return location;
}
}
```

Then I have a Clock class that extends the superclass and has some more values.

```
public class Clock extends Meter
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
public double minTime;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Clock
 */
public Clock(String regNum, String workOrNot, String location, double 
minTime)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    super(regNum, workOrNot, location);
    setMinTime(minTime);

}

//MINNIMUM TIME
public void setMinTime(double minTime){
    this.minTime = minTime;
}

public double getMinTime(){
    return minTime;
}

//EQUALS METHOD --- NOT SURE WHAT IT SHOULD DO... YET!
public boolean equals (Clock other){
    return location.equals(other.location);
}

public String toString(){
    String retur = super.toString() + "regNum: " + regNum +
                                      "Does it work: " + workOrNot +
                                      "Location: " + location +
                                      "Min time value: " + minTime;
    return retur;
}
}
```

Then I have an archive class that creates an arrayList that holds the different objects and also will have a method to remove object, when the user gets prompted with an field where they can type in the "regNum" as a String.

Then the plan is that, it iterates over the List and finds the one object with the same "regNum" and removes it from the List.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MeterArchive
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
ArrayList<Meter> meterList = new ArrayList<Meter>();

public void createClocks(){
    Clock clockOne = new Clock("KH001", "Yes", "ClassRoom005", 0.0);
    meterList.add(clockOne);
    Clock clockTwo = new Clock("KH002", "Yes", "ClassRoom006", 0.0);
    meterList.add(clockTwo);
}

public void remove( String regNumInput){
    for(Meter meter : meterList){
        for(int i = 0; i < meterList.size(); i++){
            if(regNumInput == meterList.get(i).getRegNum()){
                remove(meterList.get(i));
            }else{
                System.out.println("Did not found");
            }
        }
    }
}

public void showAll2(){
    System.out.println(meterList);
}
}
```

Can anyone explain how to make the remove method in MeterArchive class remove the object that I want to remove, when I type in the correct "regNum" in the inputfield. I know that I can use the remove() method but not sure how to use it here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `removeIf` would be a lot easier:

```
int size = meterList.size();
meterList.removeIf(e -> regNumInput.equals(e.getRegNum()));
if(size == meterList.size()) System.out.println("Did not found");
```

Comment: Nice, that actually work. The formatting was a little new to me, I would think that you had to use {some code} and else{some other code} after the if() method but it worked :)

Comment: @AndersLund This is a feature as of Java-8, "lambda expressions" i.e.`e -> regNumInput.equals(e.getRegNum())` is a [predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) which is applied to each element of the list and the [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method internally has some mechanism to remove the elements no longer needed i.e. the elements where the predicate we provided evaluates to true.

Comment: Cool can I also get this to return false if it does not find the value?

And also can I use a similar method to get an object and print it out, like getIf() or something, thanks alot :)

Comment: @AndersLund you can make your method return a boolean, `true` if removed and false otherwise `public boolean remove(String regNumInput){
        int size = meterList.size();
        meterList.removeIf(e -> regNumInput.equals(e.getRegNum()));
        return size != meterList.size();
    }` as for your last question yes it's possible, see the [stream library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Comment: I got the "Get an object"method working but I did not use the Java8 syntax cus I could not find the removeIf() method for get if you understand. Do you know what the name for the get method in the link you sent is?

`public boolean get( String regNumInput ){
        int size = meterList.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < meterList.size(); i++){
            if(regNumInput == meterList.get(i).getRegNum()){
                System.out.println(meterList.get(i));
            }
        }
        return size != meterList.size();
    }`